# Uncaught TypeError: DOMDocument::importNode()

Tags: php, mysql, domdocument

I get the following error when running `php` on my local:

```
Fri, 25 Mar 2022 03:11:55 +0000---Starting f_contracts with query 1 Fri, 25 Mar 2022 03:12:01 +0000---Starting XML -> JSON conversion
Warning: XMLReader::expand(): /private/tmp/redshift-dump.xml:1109: parser error : Extra content at the end of the document in /Users/hm/repo/f_contract_update/data.redshift.sync.hsdp/scripts/primary.php on line 1605

Warning: XMLReader::expand(): </table_data> in /Users/hm/repo/f_contract_update/data.redshift.sync.hsdp/scripts/primary.php on line 1605

Warning: XMLReader::expand(): ^ in /Users/hm/repo/f_contract_update/data.redshift.sync.hsdp/scripts/primary.php on line 1605

Warning: XMLReader::expand(): An Error Occurred while expanding in /Users/hm/repo/f_contract_update/data.redshift.sync.hsdp/scripts/primary.php on line 1605

Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: DOMDocument::importNode(): Argument #1 ($node) must be of type DOMNode, bool given in /Users/hm/repo/f_contract_update/data.redshift.sync.hsdp/scripts/primary.php:1605 Stack trace: #0 /Users/hm/repo/f_contract_update/data.redshift.sync.hsdp/scripts/primary.php(1605): DOMDocument->importNode(false, true) #1 /Users/hm/repo/f_contract_update/data.redshift.sync.hsdp/scripts/primary.php(1582): Primary->mysqlDumpXmlToJson() #2 /Users/hm/repo/f_contract_update/data.redshift.sync.hsdp/scripts/primary.php(1509): Primary->dumpData('f_contrac...', 1) #3 /Users/hm/repo/f_contract_update/data.redshift.sync.hsdp/scripts/primary.php(1460): Primary->process('f_contrac...', 1) #4 /Users/hm/repo/f_contract_update/data.redshift.sync.hsdp/scripts/primary.php(46): Primary->processFContracts() #5 /Users/hm/repo/f_contract_update/data.redshift.sync.hsdp/scripts/primary.php(1665): Primary->__construct() #6 {main} thrown in /Users/hm/repo/f_contract_update/data.redshift.sync.hsdp/scripts/primary.php on line 1605
```

The exact same script runs perfectly when running on the server, but gives me the above error when running on local.
When I look at the `XML` dump, and compare it to the dump on the server, I notice that the XML doesn't close off properly :

[image]

Compared to the server :

[image]

This is the script which it is complaining about :

```
 private function mysqlDumpXmlToJson()
    {
        if (file_exists($this->json_file)) {
            unlink($this->json_file);
        }

        $z = new \XMLReader();
        $z->open($this->xml_file);

        $doc = new \DOMDocument();

        while ($z->read() && $z->name !== 'row') ;

        $f = fopen($this->json_file, 'a+');

        while ($z->name === 'row') {
            $data = [];
            $node = simplexml_import_dom($doc->importNode($z->expand(), true));

            foreach ($node as $col) {
                $value = (string)$col;
                $value = str_replace('0000-00-00 00:00:00', '', $value);
                $data[(string)$col['name']] = $value;
            }

            fwrite($f, json_encode($data));

            $z->next('row');
        }

        fclose($f);
    }
```

Could it be that the `mysqldump` is limiting output size and where are these configurations set?

EDIT********
The following steps gets executed:

```
 private function process($table, $query)
    {
        $this->info('Starting ' . $table . ' with query ' . $query);
        $this->dumpData($table, $query);
        $this->info('Compressing JSON');
        $this->compressJson();
        $this->info('Moving to S3');
        $this->moveToS3();
        $this->info('Moving data to staging table');
        $this->copyData($table);
        $this->info('Finished ' . $table . ' with query ' . $query);
    }
```

The failure occurs during `dumpData` :

```
 private function dumpData($table, $query)
    {
        if (file_exists($this->xml_file)) {
            unlink($this->xml_file);
        }
        if ($table=='c')
        {
            system(sprintf('mysql -h rds.sdp.com -u redshift -****** --xml --database onnet   --execute "select columns from c" >%s'
                , $this->xml_file));
        }
        else {
            system(sprintf(
                'mysqldump --single-transaction --no-tablespaces -h rds -u redshift -***** --xml onnet %s --where="%s"> %s',
                $table,
                $query,
                $this->xml_file
            ));
        }

        if ($table == 's_m') {
            system(sprintf(
                'sed -i "s/<..>/__#__/g" %s',
                $this->xml_file
            ));

            system(sprintf(
                'iconv -c -f utf8 -t ascii < %s > %s',
                $this->xml_file,
                $this->xml_file . '.tmp'
            ));

            system(sprintf(
                'strings %s > %s',
                $this->xml_file . '.tmp',
                $this->xml_file
            ));
        };

        $this->info('Starting XML -> JSON conversion');
        $this->mysqlDumpXmlToJson();
        $this->info('Finished XML -> JSON conversion');

        return (filesize($this->json_file) > 1000);
    }
```

Hope that clarifies.

File systems are:

```
private $xml_file = '/tmp/rsh-dmp.xml';
private $json_file = '/tmp/rsh-dmp.json';
private $json_file_compressed = '/tmp/rsh-dmp.json.gz';
private $json_file_s3 = 's3://sdp-ew/rsh-dmp.json.gz';
```

Comment: How do you run mysqldump?

Comment: @shingo - Ive updated the question to include the `mysqlDumpXmlToJson` function.

Comment: Question still remains: "How do you run mysqldump". You've identified the issue as mySQL dump truncating or not outputting the full file etc, so that's what needs to be debugged. The code and so on in the question appear irrelevant (except to confirm the file is not fully correct)? Unless I'm missing something. 

Note: there are limits such as your file might be restricted to 2GB - but unlikely in 1100 lines.

Comment: I want to add to the question of @Robbie: what filesystems are you writing the dump file to? On the server and on local?

Comment: @cyberbrain - Ive added the functions in question and added the file systems. Let me know if this is what you require? Not sure what else you are referring to.

Comment: Please add the command you use that runs mysqldump, and the resulting output on screen: it should look like "mysqldump -h HOST -u USER -p -X " (or longhand versions) and may or may not include other options, and ends with "/tmp/rsh-dmp.xml". Until that is provided, answering this question is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

You have stated that the exact same script runs correctly on prod, while it fails on your local. So, the source-code that you have is capable to run correctly. So, the problem must be something else.

Now, we know that `$this->xml_file` is a file on the server, prod or local and it is `XMLReader::expand()` that complains first and then, the result is a `bool` instead of a `DOMNode`, which strongly suggests that the DOM could not be properly validated.

Since you have shown that the actual file ends unexpectedly, it is highly probable that your file is not properly formed.

First of all, you need a root node. From your example we see that your root node is not being closed. So, you either have some unclosed nodes, or, you do not have a root node in the first place.

If you download the file from  prod and test your local code with that file, then you will see that it is being correctly executed. So, the bug if at the place where the file was created/generated. If you have a function/module which generates the file, then you will need to debug on how it is being generated and see why the nodes are not being closed, or why the root node is not being wrapped around your structure.